# how to include jquery.js file in checkout page

Tags: javascript

I followed the instructions as per http://www.fontis.com.au/blog/magento/using-jquery-magento
. So to include jquery.js file i have downloaded it and placed at skin/frontend/enterprise/yummjunkie/js/jquery/js.
And in page.xml

        All Pages

```
        <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery.js</name></action>
```

So when i checked at checout/onepage/ page source it does not include jquery.js file.

As checkout/onepage is 2 columns right template i have placed

```
<reference name="head">
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery.js</name>
```

in checkout.xml at `<checkout_onepage_index>`

So please help me on how to add jquery.js file

Comment: do you get any 404 load error in your browser console, looking for the declared file? if yes, then check the filename or permissions; if no then try clearing all your caches

Comment: try clearing cache and check.delete var/cache folder.

Comment: @prasad solved your problem ?

Comment: i have used flush cache storage and flush magento cache, but no use!!!

Comment: use my code give below

Answer (score 3):

You can add the following code in your theme's local.xml file.and upload your jquery.js file into the js folder and in that upload in jquery folder.

```
<layout>
    <checkout_onepage_index>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>jquery/jquery.js</script></action>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_index>
</layout>
```

Comment: i have tried but no luck